# Can I access a Windows 2016 server from a 2012 client through a 2012 server?

Tags: windows, licensing, thin-client, cal

We have a bunch of thin clients with Server 2012 CALs. These thin clients mostly run RDP to a Windows 2012 server

We want to put a SQL Server 2016 install on a Windows 2016 server. These are all separately licensed.
Programs running on the 2012 server will then access the SQL Server 2016 database running on the Windows 2016 server.

We have been informed that this will cause a licensing issue with Microsoft and that each of the thin clients will need to also have Server 2016 CALs in order to keep Microsoft happy.

This seems plausible but unnecessarily greedy, even for Microsoft.
Does anyone have any information that will clarify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be you will think use sql server vnext on linux instead of Windows. This will decrease yor licence costs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-vnext

Comment: Well, yeah, we have a few Linux servers but honestly we don't have the expertise in maintaining them, nobody likes using the damn things, and we've got MS top to bottom throughout the organisation.